# Video length of playlist items Webchimera.js Player

Tags: javascript, web, libvlc, nw.js

**Environment**

- NW.js v0.12.3
- io.js v1.2.0
- 32 bits
- Windows 8
- [Webchimera.js (player)](https://github.com/jaruba/wcjs-player)

**The following code works** but I'm left wondering if it's the **best approach**. The requirement is to get the length of each video that's in the playlist.

To do that I use the events **onPlaying** and **onPaused**.

```
wjs = require('wcjs-player');

...

chimera_container = new wjs("#chimera_container");
chimera_player = chimera_container.addPlayer({ mute: true, autoplay: false, titleBar: "none" }); 
chimera_player.onPlaying( OnPlaying ); // Pauses player
chimera_player.onPaused( OnPaused ); // Extracts length information

var OnPlaying = function(){
    chimera_player.pause();
 };

var OnPaused = function() {
    console.log( chimera_player.itemDesc(chimera_player.currentItem()).mrl , chimera_player.length());
    if(!chimera_player.next())
        chimera_player.clearPlaylist();
};
```

At first I tried doing all the code in the event **onPlaying** but the app always crashed with no error. After checking **chimera_player.state()** it seemed that even after doing **chimera_player.pause()** the state didn't change while inside the **onPlaying** event. I figure having state **Playing** and trying to do **chimera_player.next()** causes the exception.

This way seems a bit hacky, but I can't think of another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach was definitely **not** the best. @RSATom kindly exposed the function `libvlc_media_get_duration` in the **WebChimera.js API**.

In order to get the duration all that is needed is:

```
... after adding playlist...
var vlcPlaylist = chimera_player.vlc.playlist;
for(var i=0, limit=chimera_player.itemCount(); i<limit; ++i  ){
    var vlcMedia = vlcPlaylist.items[i];
    vlcMedia.parse(); // Metadata is not available if not parsed
    if(vlcMedia.parsed)
        // Access duration via --> vlcMedia.duration
    else
        logger("ERROR -- parsePlaylist -- " + vlcMedia.mrl );
}
```

If you are going to try to get duration from files with **MPEG** format then you are in for a headache. In order to have VLC return duration of MPEG file before playing the video, it is necessary that its **Demuxer** is set to **Avformat demuxer**. Problem is you can't do that via the libvlc api. If demuxer is not set, then `vlcMedia.duration` will always return **0**.

There's two options here:

- Use `ffprobe` to access video metadata and forget doing it via libvlc
- Play with this posts' original way of getting duration via a combination of `play()` `pause()` events.

Answer (score 0):

<s>I've tried find any function in libvlc API allowed get media length without playing it - with no success. So it's very possible there are no way to get media length without playing it.</s>

I was wrong, it's possible (with `libvlc_media_get_duration`), but it's not exposed in `WebChimera.js API` yet. I'll add it if you will create issue for it on GitHub.

P.S.: And it will be great if you will create issues on GitHub for discovered crashes...

upd: required API [implemented](https://github.com/RSATom/WebChimera.js/wiki/JavaScript-API#vlcmedia)

Comment: Will do that then. I didn't create an issue because I figured it was a "works as intended" rather than a bug. I thought I was the one causing the crash because I was calling .length before state went from "playing" to "pause". Thanks.

Comment: Even if it "works as intended" - it should not lead to crash. So it's a bug without any doubt.